# How to update static HTML files with PHP

Tags: php, html

We've 700 static HTML files in folder "music". We want to put analytic code in the end of the HTML files.. like before

```
</body> </html>
```

tags.

Please anybody let me know, how its possible with PHP code?

Comment: loop through the files in that directory, open each in turn, use DomDocument to inject the additional markup you want, and write it back to the same filename

Comment: Also you may want to think over your data storage and move your content to a kind of database and generate your static files out of it.

Comment: do you want to add some html codes or php codes?

Comment: Sounds like you need a footer template :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too easy. Find all files, read content, modify content, save content.

```
<?php

// open directory
if($handle = opendir(__DIR__)) {
    // search for
    $search = '</body>';

    // replace with (</body> gets appended later in the script)
    $replace = <<< EOF

<!-- your analytics code here -->

EOF;

    // loop through entries
    while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if(is_dir($entry)) continue; // ignore entry if it's an directory

        $content = file_get_contents($entry); // open file
        $content = str_replace($search, $replace . '</body>', $content); // modify contents
        file_put_contents($entry, $content); // save file
    }
}

echo 'done';

?>
```

Comment: You probably meant `str_replace` rather than `preg_replace`, given the contents of `$search`.

Comment: i've put index.php file in my html folder, when i tested this code, html files are blank, its show Warning: file_put_contents() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\html\index.php on line 25,

Comment: Guys you are too fast! Congrats. No need to write more

Comment: @user1218948 My apologies. As the error mentions, `file_put_contents` requires two parameters instead of one. I have edited the code. I surely hope you have a backup of the old html files :(

Comment: Tim, thanks for code, yeah its working for me, but code puts two extra Angle brackets on Analytic script? why its happen?

Comment: Have you replaced `<!-- your analytics code here -->` entirely?